# RxJS .subscribe() without arguments still cause memory leak?

Tags: rxjs, observable, subscribe

I know this will cause memory leak because there is no unsubscription

```
interval(100).subscribe(console.log);
```

question is:
If I do not pass any observer into subscribe method, is it still causing memory leak? thanks

```
interval(100).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the same.

You can check it inside source code of `Observable`:

```
...
  subscribe(
    observerOrNext?: Partial<Observer<T>> | ((value: T) => void) | null,
    error?: ((error: any) => void) | null,
    complete?: (() => void) | null
  ): Subscription {
    const subscriber = isSubscriber(observerOrNext) ? observerOrNext : new SafeSubscriber(observerOrNext, error, complete);
...
```

There is `SafeSubscriber` class instance creation method if no arguments passed. And subscription works normally as you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the same.

You need to have an operator to stop the subscription (like `takeUntil`) or call `unsubscribe` on the subscription !